# How to excecute my application method when a user click on "Delete data" Android

Tags: java, android, methods, listener

Is there any way to call a method inside my android application when a user clicks on "Delete data" or "Desinstall" my application?

I persist some data on the phone and when a user wants to do any of those things, I want to delete it (cause the OS doesn´t reach so far to delete those items). The way I thought is adding a method that when the user does those actions, automatically my application excecutes it before the OS delets the other data or desinstalls my application.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to call a method inside my android application when a user clicks on "Delete data" or "Desinstall" my application?

No, sorry.

> I persist some data on the phone and when a user wants to do any of those things, I want to delete it (cause the OS doesn´t reach so far to delete those items).

Then you should consider putting that data somewhere that the OS *will* remove. For example, use `getExternalFilesDir()` rather than arbitrary spots on external storage.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is possible however whenever the application is opened you can check if this data has been deleted and if it has then call whatever you wanted to. Hope this helps.

Comment: mmmm the thing is that some information that I use in the other data is stored using SharedReferences and this is deleted when the user uninstall the application